# Почему процессор так загружается?

Tags: java, ubuntu, многопоточность, сокет

В ubuntu запущено одно приложение, и памяти он не жрет. Но загружает процессор на 100%.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код приложения (всего 2 класса):

основной класс, который слушает порт для сокета, тут есть HashMap в котором ссылки на созданные потоки, и при подключении клиента беру из него строку, это ключ для `HashMap`-а. Если в `HaspMap` есть объект с таким ключом,
то достаю ссылку из HashMap, потом внедряю новые объекты через `setters` и все, поток будет работать с новыми объектами, но с тем же клиентом. Если в `HashMap` нет такого объекта - создаю новый объект, передаю ему новые созданные `Socket`, `PrintWriter`, `BufferedReader` и стартую. Когда клиент отключится - делаю `Socket = null`, `PrintWriter=null`, `BufferedReader=null`. И жду когда появится новый `Soket`. Тем временем поток жив и не умирает. Так сделал потому что клиентов будет не так много. Всего около 100 клиентов. Код второго класса внизу.

```
public class MainSocket {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HashMap<String,SecondSocket> hashMap = new HashMap();
        System.out.println(" _____________________________________________");
        System.out.println("|                                             |");
        System.out.println("|       KOVER_SAMOLET(COURIER) STARTED!       |");
        System.out.println("|_____________________________________________|");

        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5322);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        PrintWriter printWriter = null;
        String clientKey = null;
        //Начинаем ожидать подключение клиентов
        while(true){
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            try
            {
                 printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
                 bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("cp1251")));
                 clientKey = bufferedReader.readLine();//<==========2
                //System.out.println("key ot klienta"+clientKey);
            }catch (Exception e){}
            //Когда есть новое подключение запускаем новый поток для работы с ним

            if(hashMap.size()!=0){
                    if(hashMap.get(clientKey)!=null){
                        SecondSocket mySocketThread = hashMap.get(clientKey);
                        mySocketThread.setSocket(socket);
                        mySocketThread.setBufferedReader(bufferedReader);
                        mySocketThread.setPrintWriter(printWriter);
                        printWriter.println("+");//<==========3
                        //System.out.println("Объект найден");
                    }else{
                        printWriter.println("++");//<==========3
                        SecondSocket mySocketThread = new SecondSocket(socket,bufferedReader,printWriter);
                        hashMap.put(clientKey,mySocketThread);
                        mySocketThread.start();
                    }
            }else{
                printWriter.println("++");//<==========3
                SecondSocket mySocketThread = new SecondSocket(socket,bufferedReader,printWriter);
                hashMap.put(clientKey, mySocketThread);
                mySocketThread.start();
            }
            System.out.println(" _____________________________________");
            System.out.println("| NOVYI KURER : "+clientKey);
            System.out.println("| OBSHEE CHISLO KUREROV : "+hashMap.size());
            System.out.println("|_____________________________________");
        }

    }
}
```

и второй класс, в котором есть поток, а в нем вечный цикл. Есть еще конструктор и гет/сет-ы. Просто для того, чтобы сетить новые объекты. Логика тут простая: проверяю одну таблицу. В ней только одно поле, в котором может быть значение `1` или `0`. если значение один то это означает что в другой таблице появилась новая запись, и делаю запрос на эту таблицу. и передаю его клиенту.

```
class SecondSocket extends Thread{
    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://..........";

    Connection connection = null;
    CallableStatement cstmt = null;
    String userId = null;
    String xml = null;
    //private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SecondSocket.class);
    Document document = null;
    Elements xmlTag = null;
    Element e = null;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    PrintWriter printWriter = null;
    Socket socket = null;
    public SecondSocket(Socket socket,BufferedReader bufferedReader,PrintWriter printWriter){
        this.socket = socket;
        this.bufferedReader = bufferedReader;
        this.printWriter = printWriter;
        try {
            // Establish the connection.
            //Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        }catch(Exception e){
            try {
                connection.rollback();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            xml = bufferedReader.readLine();
            //System.out.println("first text in socket!=null : "+xml);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            cstmt = connection.prepareCall("{call xml_parser(?,?)}");
            cstmt.setString(1, xml);
            cstmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
            cstmt.execute();
            //System.out.println("second text in socket!=null : "+cstmt.getString(2));
            document = Jsoup.parse(cstmt.getString(2));
            xmlTag = document.getElementsByTag("codeid");
            try{
                e = xmlTag.get(0);
                userId = e.text();
            }catch (Exception e){}

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            while(socket!=null){
                if(userId!=null){
                    try {
                        cstmt = connection.prepareCall("{call xml_parser_new(?,?)}");
                        cstmt.setInt(1, Integer.valueOf(userId));
                        cstmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.INTEGER);
                        cstmt.execute();
                        printWriter.println(cstmt.getString(2));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try{
                        while ((xml = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            //System.out.println("last text in socket!=null : "+xml);
                            cstmt.execute();
                            if (cstmt.getString(2).equals("1")) {
                                printWriter.println(cstmt.getString(2));
                            }else {
                                printWriter.println("0");
                            }
                        }
                    }catch(IOException e){
                    } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            cstmt.close();
                            socket.close();
                            socket = null;
                            xml = "";
                            e = null;
                            xmlTag = null;
                            document = null;
                            bufferedReader.close();
                            bufferedReader = null;
                            printWriter.close();
                            printWriter = null;
                            //System.out.println("сработал finally block");
                            //log.info("все обьекты уничтожены.сокет закрыт,поток мертв");
                        } catch (SQLException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                //System.out.println("сработал конечный while(socket!=null)");
            }
            //System.out.println("Работает while true");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public BufferedReader getBufferedReader() {
        return bufferedReader;
    }

    public void setBufferedReader(BufferedReader bufferedReader) {
        this.bufferedReader = bufferedReader;
    }

    public PrintWriter getPrintWriter() {
        return printWriter;
    }

    public void setPrintWriter(PrintWriter printWriter) {
        this.printWriter = printWriter;
    }

    public Socket getSocket() {
        return socket;
    }

    public void setSocket(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }
}
```

Comment: И думал что ранее у меня были проблемы с памятью.

Comment: То что вы там рекомендовали я делал. но проблем но возникало.Нагружал приложение по максимуму.и все работало отлично.И даже GC работал хорошо.

Comment: В любом случае вопрос слишком общий для Stack Overflow. Вам нужно самому найти часть кода, которая нагружает процессор. Примените подход «разделяй и властвуй» и составьте [минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Сейчас вопрос имеет вид «отладьте 200 строк моего кода» и подходит скорее для фриланс-биржи чем для сайта вопросов и ответов.

Comment: Любой бесконечный цикл, в котором нет `Thread.sleep()` внутри, будет грузить процессор.

Comment: @Alex Chermenin но у меня же есть Thread.sleep(1000).1 секунда.Или этого времени мало чтобы не грузить процессор?

Comment: @ЭмЭрИкс_007 а в классе `MainSocket`?

Comment: @Alex Chermenin нет.Это в SecondSocket.Но в классе MainSocket тоже есть бесконечный цикл, но он же ждет подключения клиентов по Socket.И когда я делаю Socket.accet(); цикл же останавливается или это не тоже самое что и Thread.sleep()?.

Comment: А зачем вы делаете двойной бессмысленный цикл? Когда одним решается.

Comment: У вас есть один из циклов без Thread.sleep(1000). В нем и проблема.

Comment: @And спасибо....

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov пасибо....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

тяжело без логов делать диагностику, остается только гадать.

наиболее "слабое" место имхо здесь:

```
while(true){
    while(socket!=null){
        if(userId!=null){
```

если по какой либо причине условие второго цикла выполняется, а условие "иф"а нет, то поток зациклиться без всяких слипов и ничто его уже не остановит.

но это всего лишь домыслы. добавьте пожалуйста лог, или еще лучше тест.