# Помогите с алгоритмом.Без цикла

Tags: java, сокет, while

Здравствуйте.Нужно сделать переподключение `Socket`-а без цикла.Сейчас у меня так :

```
while(true){
  Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
}
```

Нужно убрать while.Но нужно подключить около сотни клиентов.А то цикл загружает процессор на 100%;

Comment: Ну, так он подключит и дальше перестанет загружать - accept() будет просто висеть, цикл не будет крутиться. Ну, можете Thread.sleep() добавить.

Comment: И еще. Просто подключать клиентов ведь смысла нет. Обычно после этого (то есть в этом самом цикле, кроме accept()) что-то с ними делают, например, создают на каждого новый поток с while...read().

Comment: Да.после подключения клиента работа с ней ведётся в отдельном потоке(read,write и.т.д).А Thread.sleep() особо не помог.

Comment: Покажитесь весь код этого цикла, вместе с Thread.sleep(), а не 1 строчку.

Comment: Сейчас.........

Comment: А зачем sleep, если accept блочит? Может не цикл грузит проц?

Comment: Все твердят что нагрузка из-за вечного цикла.Я тоже думал про блокировку с accept();

Comment: @SmInc https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/809790/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F?noredirect=1#comment1284584_809790

Comment: @ЭмЭрИкс_007 да ничего подобного. У меня в приложении в условно-бесконечном цикле крутится `Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();` без `Thread.sleep` (который там попросту вреден будет), и никаких проблем с процессором из-за этого нет.

Comment: @Regent ясно.спасибо.